# bind Knockoutjs arrays to Bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, slider

I'm trying to implement a bootstrap slider in a webapplication and use knockoutjs for the data handling.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    function ViewModel() {
        singleValue  = ko.observable(20)
        arrayValues  = ko.observableArray([20, 50])            
    }
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel)
})
```

**HTML**

```
<input 
  type                ='text' 
  data-slider-min     = 0 
  data-slider-max     = 100
  data-slider-step    = 1 
  data-slider-tooltip ='hide'
  data-provide        ='slider'
  data-slider-value   = 20
  data-bind           = 'value: singleValue'
/>

<p data-bind='text: singleValue'></p>
```

That works perfectly fine. If I change the value of the slider, the value in p is changing accordingly.

```
<input 
  type                ='text' 
  data-slider-min     = 0 
  data-slider-max     = 100
  data-slider-step    = 1 
  data-slider-tooltip ='hide'
  data-provide        ='slider'
  data-slider-value   = [20, 40]
  data-bind           = 'value: arrayValues'
/>

<p data-bind='text: arrayValues()'></p> 
// output is 20,50, so knockout is taking precedence, 
// because I set the initial value to [20, 40] in html
```

If I change the value of the slider, it seems the values are changing accordingly. But it's not an array anymore, its a string value. But the minimum and maximun values are changing correctly with the slider.

```
<p data-bind='text: arrayValues()[0]'></p>
```

Here the output is 20 when site is rendered. Which is what I expected.
But as soon as I start to move the slider, the array is becoming a string and the output changes to 2, which is the first char of 20,40.

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the value binding for `<input>`, `<textarea>` etc. really just understands string values. This is not true for `<select>`, which accepts arbitrary data types, even objects.

My suggestion would be to work-around the problem. In the example below, I use a writable computed to parse '20,40' into an array of the form you described. You might just provide such a computed using `data-bind = 'value: val'`.

```js
let _val = ko.observable([20, 50]);
let val = ko.computed({
  read: () => _val(),
  write: v => {
    _val(v.split(',').map(n => parseInt(n)));
  },
});

console.log(val());
val('20,40');
console.log(val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: **thanks** svschmidt! this did the trick!  isn't as nice as I would like, but it works. thanks for the info, that input only excepts strings as value!
One question: you used let _val = ko.observable([20, 50]). why doesn't you use observableArray?

Comment: @HexXx Glad I could help! To be honest, I did not think of observableArrays when answering. I think you could easily use one instead.